# Javascript map with composite keys

Tags: javascript, dictionary

In JavaScript I want to store values to compound keys, similar to a C# dictionary with a tuple as key. This is where I came across the Map class. However, it does not seem to work quite as well as I would like it to. Here's my current approach:

```js
var test = new Map();

test.set({a: 1, b: 1}, 'Bla');
test.set({a: 5, b: 7}, 'Blub');

test.get({a: 1, b: 1}); // ==> Returns undefined; would expect 'Bla'
```

I guess, that this has something to do that both objects with `{a: 1, b: 1}` have a different memory address and therefore are the same, but not identical. The `Dictionary` class in c# uses a hash function in background. Is there something similar in JS? Or a much easier approach?

My real key object consistst of three strings.

Comment: Your analysis is right: `Map` uses reference equality on the keys and not value equality.  If your objects just have three fixed strings, can you synthesize a key for map by combining them?  E.g. `makeKey = (({s1, s2, s3}) => \`${s1}~${s2}~${s3}\``? Then `test.set(makeKey({a: 1, b: 1}), 'Bla')` ... `test.get(makeKey({a: 1, b: 1})`

Comment: Sure, that would work. Would you rather use the `Map` class or a simple object in that case?

Comment: Either one would be fine. To my mind, this restriction on `Map` makes it much less useful than it could be.

Comment: @ScottSauyet If you want, you can post your idea as an answer.

Comment: Nah, simple enough to be just a comment.  Besides, the `JSON.stringify` comment from 
Captain Mhmdrz_A is most likely a better idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. It works like this because in Javascript you usually operate primitive objects that don't have all this hashing behavior attached to them out of the box. Nothing stops you from implementing your own Dictionary with hash function in background though

```js
class Dictionary {
  map = {}

  constructor(hashFunction) {
    this.hashFunction = hashFunction
  }

  set(key, item) {
    this.map[this.hashFunction(key)] = item
  }

  get(key) {
    return this.map[this.hashFunction(key)]
  }

  delete(key) {
    delete this.map[this.hashFunction(key)]
  }
}

const dict = new Dictionary((keyObject) => JSON.stringify(keyObject))
dict.set({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'hello')
console.log(dict.get({ a: 1, b: 2 })) // hello
```

As to what to use, Map or object, the difference between Map and object is simply that object only supports string keys (also Symbols but irrelevant right now) while Map supports any value at a cost of using more resources, less compatibility with old browsers, and it's generally less handy to use than object (and also stops GC from cleaning out those objects you use as keys). That said, object is your choice here

Answer (score 5):

`{}` this operator will create a new object every time; and a new object will have a different object refenece each time; if you save the object reference and use that for multiple operation its ok; but since you are trying to use a new object refence every time it won't work; you may either use a primitive type as key, or same object reference like the snippet below

```js
//approach 1 using same object reference
var test = new Map();
var obj = {a: 1, b: 1};
test.set(obj, 'Bla');
test.set({a: 5, b: 7}, 'Blub');
let result = test.get(obj); 
console.log(result);

// aproach 2 using JSON.stringify
test = new Map();
test.set(JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 1}), 'Bla');
test.set({a: 5, b: 7}, 'Blub');
result = test.get(JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 1})); 
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Right, if you still have access to that `obj`.  But presumably the OP doesn't, or this wouldn't be an issue.  Think about using this `Map` as a cache for an expensive operation.  You want to see if the current data has already been calculated, so you want to check if the map has an object with these three string values.  You can't because that's not how `Map` works.  This is a bit of a shame.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. Unfortunately, this does not work in my particular case. The objects have to be recreated before they can be read out.  In other words: When reading, I no longer have a reference to the original object, but have to regenerate the key from three separate attributes.

Comment: @AndréReichelt yeah sure, you may even consider `JSON.stringify()` that object as use the object string as the key; even if two object have different reference, but identical structure; the json.stringify result would be the same

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A That would be an idea as well.

Comment: This would work, but efficiency might suffer. For example, i want to use typed arrays as keys, and just comparing their values would be cheaper than creating new strings, i reckon. Not that i have profiled this.

Comment: JSON.stringify can be problematic as `JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2}) !== JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1})`

Comment: @ziv yeah that's correct; we should keep that in mind if we decide to use this approach; thanks for mentioning.